# DocuSign - data validation with tags

Tags: docusignapi

I need to create DocuSign envelopes using custom tags with data validation. The value that the recipient enters in the custom tag needs to be validated so that the recipient does not enter the value more than certain value.

I tried using regular expressions but they only validate the entered number for a specific range.

Does DocuSign provide a way to validate the entered number to be less than a specific number?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [docusign calculated fields](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-calculated-fields) for validation.

> You can use mathematical signs for inequality, such as greater than or
>   less than, to construct formulas containing an evaluation of the
>   result. For example, if you have a group of fields that must add up to
>   less than or equal to 100, you can use a formula to evaluate the
>   total, and then show a conditional note with a warning to correct the
>   values.
>
> [Field A] + [Field B] + [Field C] <= 100

In your case, since you want the entered number to be less than a specific number, you can show a validation message when 
[Field A] > {Your Value}

EDIT:
This is how the [PostEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request will look like. Please notice the three tab types. In the below example, The formula tab will evaluate to 1 when numberTab(Amount) is greater than 100. This will trigger the conditional Note to display the validation message.

```
{
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      { 
        "email": "johnsmith@xyz.com",
        "name": "john smith",
        "recipientId": 1,
        "tabs": 
        {
          "numberTabs": [
            {
              "name": "Amount Tab",
              "required": "true",
              "tabLabel": "Amount",
              "documentId": "1",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "xPosition": "70",
              "yPosition": "119",
              "width": "42",
              "height": "11",
            }
          ],
          "noteTabs": [
            {
              "value": "Amount cannot be more than hundred",
              "name": "Note to recipient",
              "tabLabel": "Validation Message",
              "fontColor": "brightred",
              "documentId": "1",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "xPosition": "132",
              "yPosition": "112",
              "width": "231",
              "height": "20",
              "conditionalParentLabel": "NumberValidation",
              "conditionalParentValue": "1",
              "tabType": "note"
            }
          ],
          "formulaTabs": [
            {
              "formula": "[Amount] >  100",
              "roundDecimalPlaces": "0",
              "name": "Formula Tab",
              "locked": "true",
              "concealValueOnDocument": "true",
              "tabLabel": "NumberValidation",
              "documentId": "1",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "tabType": "formula"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "doc.pdf",
      "fileExtension" : "pdf",
      "documentBase64": "{Removed}"
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "Testing Validation",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this case, I have to create another tag and have recipient enter a value in that so that I can validate another tag value based upon the first tag value. The value that I want to validate the tag value is different for each envelope and I do not want the recipient to change that value. Is there a way to create a tag but do not allow recipient to change the tag value?

Comment: I was able to create a tag and setup the property of the tag as "locked" so the recipient cannot edit the value of the tag. I tried using calculated fields as below: I created a tag with a value that I want to validate with, setup the initial value of that tag and then locked that tag. Then I created another tag for the recipient to enter the value. Now, I had to create a third tag with formula to check if the value that recipient have entered is below the first tag value. I was able to create the formula tag fine but am not able to display the validation message with that tag. Please advise.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I have tried creating an envelope with these three tags but the formula tag does not show up during signing. I tried simply formula such as [Amount] + 5 so that I know that this tag works but still the tag does not show up. I have been trying in our demo account.I have used formula tags before and they always worked. Is there anything that I need to check for them?

Comment: In my example,  I have set  (concealValueOnDocument = true) and did not specify the X,Y postion. This will cause formula tab to appear just as a (*) on the top left corner.  If you want the formula tab to appear on the document then you will need to set the X,Y position correctly and set (concealValueOnDocument = false)